# File System Unknown after decryption with Veracrypt Rescue Disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting, veracrypt

My laptop had 2 veracrypt (1.25.9) disks (one as system, and the other with the same password) with windows installed in the first disk.
Suddenly it could´t boot  anymore (May be it happened because, I removed disks to change them for other that I wanted to install linux, and although I thought the laptop was switched off, it actually was suspended)

I mounted the disks with veracrypt in linux, and both of them had all my stuff there.

So I used the Veracrypt Rescue disk to decrypt disk.
After 20 hours it said the process was successful.
I thought that it will decrypt only the system disk, but It changed both of them.
But now they don't have anything....

Windows repair can´t mount C nor E disks.

Examining both disk with linux,

- gparted says File System Unknown.
  Information: Warning: Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:

  - The file system is damaged
  - The file system is unknown to GParted
  - There is no file system available (unformatted)
  - The device entry /dev/sdb2 is missing
- gnome-disk-utility says Contents: Unknown, Partition Type: NTFS/exFAT/HPFS
- trying to mount with Veracrypt says Wrong fs type, bad option, badsuperblock on /dev/mapper/veracrypt1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

UPDATE 1:

I have tried to mount again both disks with veracrypt under linux.
The disk that contained windows is still usable with veracrypt (using preboot authentication) and have all the data.
The secondary disk, is not usable with veracrypt.
So up to now I only have lost 1 disk.

Maybe the Rescue Disk have decrypted the secondary disk instead of system disk, but with the algorithms of a preboot disk?
Could this process be recovered?
could this be something similar to 'veracrypt 1.19 bug does not correctly decrypt the first 50 MB'?
(TestDisk complains about both of them)

UPDATE 2:

I removed secondary disk, and left alone the system disk, suddenly it  booted with no problems after set the veracrypt password!!!
So the secondary disk was the disk that Rescue Disk decrypted, and now its useless....
May be the veracrypt boot loader got confused with the disk when I removed them, to install linux in another disk, and then conected
again after linux instalation. Although they were in the same position (my secondary disk is in a Dvd Ssd Caddy)

---

MORAL:

1- When veracrypt boot can´t boot, try to leave the system disk alone.

2- When using the Rescue Disk, leave only the system disk.

---

Any ideas to recover secondary disk? Is the Veracrypt Rescue Disk a reversible process?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not the first to lose data in Veracrypt. Encrypting without backup is dangerous.

Comment: Suggestion for future use: encrypting a *folder*, not the whole file system with OS, is somewhat safer. Also, make drive images periodically, keeping a few, should one be found bad.